# UnityEditor.InspectorWindow.OnSelectionChange() exeption

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I started to use google play services in my project some time ago.
The error is appearing randomly. When I go to Window/Google Play Games/Setup/Android Setup... and than click Setup the error is gone, but after few compilations it appears again. I don't know what can be causing this issue.

I though it is related to Google Play Games, but it didn't happen before so I'm not sure if it is the case.

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object
>       UnityEditor.InspectorWindow.OnSelectionChange () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/InspectorWindow.cs:148)
>       System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder,
>   System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
>   (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:222)
>       Rethrow as TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>       System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder,
>   System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
>   (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:232)
>       System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MethodBase.cs:115)
>       UnityEditor.HostView.Invoke (System.String methodName, System.Object obj) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/HostView.cs:285)
>       UnityEditor.HostView.Invoke (System.String methodName) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/HostView.cs:278)
>       UnityEditor.HostView.OnSelectionChange () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/HostView.cs:167)
>       UnityEditor.AssetDatabase:Refresh()
>       GooglePlayGames.Editor.GPGSUpgrader:.cctor() (at Assets/GooglePlayGames/Editor/GPGSUpgrader.cs:112)
>       UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes()

I can build the project with this error and it seems to work, but it's annoying. What I can do to track the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known **Google Play Games** bug. You can read more about this [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/2029).

Comment: It started happening a few days ago, not from the time I installed it so I think something is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Unity 2017.2.0f3 fixes this.

It's broken on subsequent builds